# Selenium - how to verify form not submitted on click? (client validation works)

Tags: c#, selenium

Is there a way to verify that the page is not reloaded when click "Submit" using Selenium?

Currently the test instructs the browser to open a submit form and immediately clicks "Submit" without filling the fields.

In that way I will verify that the client side validation works and doesn't make unnecessary requests to server.

I'm using C# by the way - if it matters.

Comment: On a successful submit what occurs?

Comment: The server renders the same page in case of error, on success it returns a redirect to success page, I search something like event handler whether the page is refreshing, loading, or on Navigation occurred  etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case you would have to verify the page upon submission, either the successful page or original, to determine if the form input was successful :)

Normally you would verify the error message returned on the given pop-up or sign-in form, which would lead you to conclude that the input was unsuccessful, but in this case, that doesn't seem to be possible.

Asserting the given page URI and/or page elements, will help you determine the outcome.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will work on this case to make some extension method...and will share some solutions,

Comment: @mihkov If you feel like the comment was hopeful in reaching a solution, don't be afraid to mark it when you get a moment ^_^

Answer (score 1):

If only a reload check is needed, you can check for staleness of an element that was present on the page earlier. A small code example:

```
    public bool IsNewPageLoaded(IWebElement elementToGoStale)
    {
        try
        {
            var enabled = elementToGoStale.Enabled;
            return false;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is StaleElementReferenceException || ex is NoSuchElementException)
            {
                return true; // Expected exception on accessing stale element: page has been renewed
            }

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

The nice thing is that you don't need any extra information about what happens after a page load: all you need is to store an IWebElement on which you can check later on.

I use similar checks in my tests. Although I still consider the try/catch part ugly, so far it has proven to be extremely reliable.

Comment: Nice solution, Is it working in other browsers - Firefox, Internet explorer, Edge? Currently I have only 2 tests using Chrome

Comment: I mainly work in Chrome and Firefox, though the few tests I wrote for IE worked with this concept as well. IE gives many other (unrelated) issues though, so eventually I limited our testing there.

Answer (score 0):

based on @Tybs 's answer, I've managed a helper class.

```cs
public class NoReloadVerificationContext : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IWebElement bodyElement;
    public NoReloadVerificationContext(IWebDriver webDriver)
    {
        this.bodyElement = webDriver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
    }

    public void Dispose() => Assert.True(this.bodyElement.Enabled);
}
```

I've seen such approach in some software projectes that provides API - for example creating a context that can make operation without be signed as admin until it's disposed.

An example usage:

```cs
// This block asserts that no reload occurred after executing operation inside
// Else it throws an exception - which is OK for me. 
using (new NoReloadVerificationContext(driver))
{
    // this will submit the form and cause page reload because of missing client vlidations
    driver.FindElementByCssSelector("form input[type=submit]").Click();
} // The exception will occur here.
```

I don't know whether this is the best solution, but it will work in most cases (not only in forms)

The other approach was to get the value of `__RequestVerificationToken` inside my form (MVC generates it at the end of each form), then perform some actions, after that get the value again and compare with the old one. But this will work only for form submits.